# Displaying a partial view from another controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to generate a partial view that will allow me to display recent context on the home page (Index). However, the model is only returning as NULL.

Podcast controller method:

```
// Generates list of most recent 2 podcasts
public async Task<IActionResult> _RecentPodcasts()
{
        var recentList = from p in _context.Podcast
                         select p;
        recentList = recentList.OrderByDescending(p => p.PublishDate).Take(2);            

        return View(await recentList.ToListAsync());
}
```

Partial view (Podcasts/_RecentPodcasts.cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<ComesNaturally.Models.Podcast>

@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "_RecentPodcasts";
}


<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="table-title">
    <table class="table-fill">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Recent Podcasts</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
@if (Model == null)
{
        <tr> No items found</tr>}
else
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
     { 
         <tr>
             <td><a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="alert-link">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></td>
         </tr>
     }}
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Main view (Home/Index.cshtml)

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Podcasts/_RecentPodcasts.cshtml");
```

Comment: Is the model in your main view the same as the one in your partial view? If not have your tried passing the model as a parameter to the partial view in the `Partial` statement? (or is it an expression?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@await Html.PartialAsync("_RecentPodcasts")` razor knows how to find it, by convention.  Now as for passing the data you need to have some sort of means to actually get the data right?

`public async Task<IActionResult> _RecentPodcasts()` beatings shall be doled out for the naming of that METHOD (hint drop the `_`). Actually surprised the compiler didn't complain.

Home / Index.cshtml will have a viewmodel which will have a property of type... you guessed it.. "RecentPodCasts"

```
//fill it from HomeController...
public class HomeViewModel(){
    public IEnumerable<Podcast> RecentPodcasts {get;set;}
}

//HomeController.cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(){
     var vm = new HomeViewModel();
     vm.RecentPodcasts = await _context.Podcasts.OrderByDescending(p => p.PublishDate).Take(2).ToListAsync();

     return View(vm);
}


//home/index.cshtml
@model YourNameSpace.Models.HomeViewModel  


@*somewhere in Home/Index.cshtml*@
@await Html.PartialAsync("_RecentPodCasts", Model.RecentPodcasts )
```

that should just about cover it... The rest of the blanks and ...'s will be for you discover on your .net core/ mvc journey

Comment: This set me in the right direction. Thank You!